# NFC Tag Generating problem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest, nfc

I am working on a NFC Android Project. I want to import "`import.android.nfc.tag;`" in my project. But it generates error.

When I am going to write package import android.nfc.__;  Then ADT plugins shows only four option  that are  nfcAdapter ,NdefMessage, NdefRecord, FormatException .   But I think there should be more options.  I am too much in confusion. Can anybody suggest me solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**:

You should read documentation. You can find doc about NFC here: [android.nfc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/package-summary.html). There are only for classes `NfcManager`, `NfcAdapter`, `NdefMessage` and `NdefRecord`. That's it.

If you are confused about how to use them, please see [Near Field Communication](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html) article and [NFCDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/index.html) example.

---

You most likely using wrong SDK Level. Make sure that you're using at least Android SDK Level 9.

Comment: Thanks Inazaruk ..for your suggestions.. Well ! i have found the problem. But your suggestion is also helpful to find out the answer of this question .so I accept this anwer..  Thanks again.